# Determine what user called my stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm sure this has been asked, but search isn't returning the answer.

In a stored procedure, how do I get the value of the user/login that called the stored procedure (name?), assuming I don't already have server_user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in sql 2005

select suser_name()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187934.aspx

SUSER_NAME ( [ server_user_id ] ) 
server_user_id

Is the login identification number of the user. server_user_id, which is optional, is int. server_user_id can be the login identification number of any SQL Server login or Microsoft Windows user or group that has permission to connect to an instance of SQL Server. If server_user_id is not specified, the login identification name for the current user is returned.

--

edit: just tried it with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)

with integrated and sql security

and all these:

`select suser_name()`

select suser_sname()

select original_login()

select system_user

correctly return the logged user... I guess there's some problem with your configuration...

saludos

sas

Comment: returns NULL in sql 2008, or at least in my instance of it.

Comment: mmm... don't have a sql 2008 at hand right now... maybe select original_login()???

Comment: on sql 2005, these all return the logged user

select suser_name()
select suser_sname()
select original_login()
select system_user

Comment: Yes, it also seems to work on the other setups I have.  it must be something quirky with this one setup.